# Maintaining Aggregate Root references in CQRS. Sagas vs command handlers

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

I'm building a prototype to explore CQRS and Event sourcing.

Say I have 2 root Aggregates,  **Organisation** and **Position**, a one to many relationship with a need for a two way reference.  Positions can exist without Organisations (freelancers for example).

For this discussion lets assume both Organisation and Position objects have been created.  I now have an `AddPositionToOrganisation` command.

Making sure the references are in sync I see I have two options.

1. The Organisation command handler can generate two events.  One for the Organisation and one for the Position adding the corresponding references.
2. Create a Saga that listens for an `PositionAddedOrganisation` event and create a `AddOrganisationToPositionCommand`.

Is there a problem with using the Organisation command handler to generate events for the Position?  On the plus side it groups related functionality together (references), but makes the Organisation responsible for some of the Position logic.

Some insight from more experienced developers would be most welcome.

Comment: No, i dont think there is a problem in principle, with option 1.  
To me, its always the Aggregate that must emit the event, but if the command handler wants to call two aggregates into scope and perform an action on each, take those two events and publish them together within the bounds of one database transaction, that should be fine.
I'm still learning regards how event sourced systems should be implemented, so I'm sure someone will correct me!

Comment: Thanks for the response.  From my understanding commands can only target one aggregate.  Command handlers validate the command and create the resulting events. The aggregates apply these events before they are broadcast to the rest of the system.  Therefore my current design has the aggregates also acting as the command handlers.  Option 1 would have the Organisation creating events for the Position (a bit smelly) but it does keep the logic together rather than spreading it over 2 command handlers.

Comment: ok, i've never seen it said before that one command handler must only target one aggregate.  In my mind, the command handler makes calls to one aggregate usually, which results only in a list of local events being generated, these events are persisted to a store.
What would be the harm in applying operations to a second aggregate, and then persisting its events?

Comment: But the more I think about it, the second option seems preferable.  You would want to have the second aggregate functionality decoupled in most cases.  In your example, it just felt a bit more difficult to see this, as both operations are so intrinsic to each other.  That if the latter operation failed, you would be very inconsistent.  So maybe this means you should model it differently....

Comment: I mean a command can only target only one aggregate.  I got most of my information from http://cqrs.nu/Faq.  Looking at http://cqrs.nu/Faq/aggregates again I see that option 1 is probably no good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An [aggregate](http://cqrs.nu/Faq/aggregates) defines a consistency boundary; every transaction is scoped to a single aggregate. Attempting to modify more than one aggregate at a time, such as in a command handler, goes against this advice.

A [process manager](http://cqrs.nu/Faq/sagas) (saga) is an ideal fit for this use case. It is an independent component that reacts to domain events in a cross-aggregate, eventually consistent manner. In its simplest form a process manager reacts to domain events and dispatches commands in response. It may also track state,  related to the process, to help correlate events between aggregates.

I would therefore suggest your second approach is preferable.

For further reading on process managers I recommend the [CQRS Journey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591569.aspx) guide written by Microsoft's Patterns & Practices team. The [Implementing Domain-Driven Design](https://vaughnvernon.co/?page_id=168) book by Vaughn Vernon is a useful reference for building an application following the CQRS architectural pattern.

Comment: Thanks, this is the approach I have taken.  I saw option one as a short cut but have been convinced it's a bad idea.

Comment: just as a side note, i just read this in Patterns, Principles and Practices of Domain-Driven Design:

Sometimes it is actually good practice to modify multiple aggregates within a transaction. But it’s
important to understand why the guidelines exist in the first place so that you can be aware of the
consequences of ignoring them.
When the cost of eventual consistency is too high, it’s acceptable to consider modifying two objects
in the same transaction. Exceptional circumstances will usually be when the business tells you that
the customer experience will be too unsatisfactory.....